# How do I export XY data from QGIS to shapefile?

Tags: qgis, convert

How do I export XY data from a comma-delimited file to a shapefile using QGIS?

Answer (score 10):

Import the XY data as a CSV (identifying the X and Y columns is the process as the geometry) and then right-click on the layer and select save-as.  When the dialog box opens, identify the output type as a shapefile (which is the default anyway) and click save.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use QGIS text delimited layer plugin to import your xy data file.
2. Select X(Longitude/Easting) and Y(Latitude/Norhting) and press OK
3. In CRS window select OSGB 1936 / British National Grid & Press OK
4. In the Layers section select the recently imported layer right click and save as shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE and thankyou for your answer to this question which I will upvote.  You will notice that I have removed your signature as per the help instruction: "[**Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**] Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!"