# How to create a shapefile in QGIS using the spreadsheet?

Tags: qgis

I have a spreadsheet which has columns (X, Y, Att1, Att2 ...). I want to create a point shapefile, all columns in the spreadsheet to be the column in the shapefile. How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: your question looks similar to  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72781/how-do-i-export-xy-data-from-qgis-to-shapefile/72807#72807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will use the Delimited Text Import feature as a one time process.

Save the spreadsheet as .csv (comma separated value) then import it into QGIS via the menu command 
`LAYER|ADD DELIMITED TEXT LAYER`

Many of the options can remain preset, although likely you will have to choose which columns hold the x y data. You may also have to select a CRS (coordinate reference system) as the second stage of the wizard. For instance for x y in decimal degrees you can choose EPSG:4326

Once the data has been imported, you then right click on the new layer and `SAVE AS` an ESRI Shapefile to create the shp format.

There is also the ability to read xl files directly but this is troublesome IMHO and does not create a shapefile.

hth

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your spreadsheet to CSV(comma separated values) using [MS Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/) or [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)
2. Use QGIS text delimited layer plugin to import your xy data file.
3. Select X(Longitude/Easting) and Y(Latitude/Norhting) and press OK
4. In CRS window select CRS (for example [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)) & Press OK
5. In the Layers section select the recently imported layer right click and save as shapefile.

Comment: text delimited import is natively available, it is not a plugin anymore

Comment: @Willy thanks for your information but i think it was not there in QGIS 1.8 and user didn't mention which version he has on his system.